# Центрирование внутри v-carousel

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Не получается выровнять по центру div внутри компонента v-carousel.

[image: div прижимается к левому краю]

```css
<style scoped>
  .title {
       position: absolute;
       bottom: 50px;
       background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
       color: white;
       font-size: 2em;
       padding: 30px;
     }
</style>
```

```html
    <v-layout row wrap class="mt-3">
      <v-flex xs12>
        <v-carousel>
          <v-carousel-item
            v-for="meetup in meetups"
            :key="meetup.id"
            :src="meetup.imageURL">
            <div class="title">{{ meetup.title }}</div>
          </v-carousel-item>
        </v-carousel>
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex class="text-xs-center mt-2">
        <p>Welcome to our meetups!</p>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
v-carousel {
    text-align: center; /* Родительскому задать выравнивание по центру */
}
.title {
    max-width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: white;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: 30px;
    display: inline-block; /* Для авто ширины блока и выравнивания */
    vertical-align: top; /* что-бы блок не съезжал вниз при добавлении контента */
    margin-top: 60px; /* Нужное расстояние */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за наводку! По факту добиться желаемого результата вышло так:

```
<style scoped>
  .carousel {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .title {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: white;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 21em;
  }
</style>
```